# unable to access members of control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write a action client to send pose command to my dynamixal servo. Following the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/Creatingdynamixelactionclient) , I created a cpp version. I had issues in accessing the member attribute **joint_names** for **control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction** object and was given

> error:
> ‘control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction’
> has no member named ‘joint_names’

The [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/api/control_msgs/html/action/FollowJointTrajectory.html) clearly shows the member attribute declared. I am really not sure what is causing the issue.

Below is a snippet of the code

```
actionlib::SimpleActionClient<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction> ac("/left_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/", true);

ROS_INFO("Waiting for action server to start.");
// wait for the action server to start
ac.waitForServer(); //will wait for infinite time

ROS_INFO("Action server started, sending goal.");

control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction goal;
goal.joint_names = {"Shoulder"};

trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectoryPoint point;
point.positions={5};
point.time_from_start=ros::Duration(5.0);

goal.desired = point;

ac.sendGoal(goal);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218695/unable-to-access-members-of-control_msgs::followjointtrajectoryaction/) by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it seems that I have misunderstood the  .action file to be like message definition. Reading the **http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib** documentation , it will seem that the action file will generate 3 message object

- FollowJointTrajectoryGoal
- FollowJointTrajectoryResult
- FollowJointTrajectoryFeedBack

each for the different action state.

The objectType  FollowJointTrajectoryGoal will be used to send the goals.

Will test this out and update the result.

---

Originally posted by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) with karma: 93 on 2015-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0